# Small questions for AJAX onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
```

So this says `onreadystatechange`, invoke function(). Can I put parameters in `function()`? Second question, what does it mean when someone writes, `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=statechanged`? Does that mean it will always be true or something?

Comment: onreadystatechange - Stores a function (or the name of a function) to be called automatically each time the readyState property changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can't use a parameter since `onreadystatechange` has no parameters to give you. What parameter are you expecting? It is simply a hook for handling the response. What you **do** have available is the `xmlhttp.readyState` which tells you if the response is ready or not, `xmlhttp.status` - the http status code (i.e. 200), and `xmlhttp.responseText` - the response itself.
2. No - that means you are assigning a variable reference (a function) to `onreadystatechange`.

I would strongly suggest using a JS framework (such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com)) to do AJAX calls - it will abstract away the low-level details you are asking about. If you must use native JS AJAX calls - [read this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters with a wrapper function:

```
var func = function(p1, p2) {/*...*/};
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  func(foo, bar);
};
```